# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) when trying to create user with email and password

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am developing a react native app using expo. I am trying to create a new user with email and password (using Firebase) but after pressing the Register button i keep getting this error message

`[FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).]`

I checked my Firebase project and double checked that i had email/password authentication enabled and I did. I also checked my Firebase config and made sure i was initialising everything correctly.

Here is my config:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'; 
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGE,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

// Initialise Firebase

export const FIREBASE_APP = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
export const FIRESTORE_DB = getFirestore(FIREBASE_APP);
```

and here is my code:

```
async function register() {
    try {
      const auth = FIREBASE_AUTH;
      const {
        email,
        password,
        boxingLevel,
        gender,
        weightClass,
        age,
        height,
        currentWeight,
        location,
        weightGoal,
        activityLevel,
        bmr,
        tdee,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      } = {
        email,
        password,
        boxingLevel,
        gender,
        weightClass,
        age,
        height,
        currentWeight,
        location,
        weightGoal,
        activityLevel,
        bmr,
        tdee,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      };

      // create a firebase account
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      // save state variables to firestore
      const db = FIREBASE_DB;
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        uid: userCredential.user.uid,
        email, //including email as a reference
        boxingLevel,
        gender,
        weightClass,
        age,
        height,
        currentWeight,
        location,
        weightGoal,
        activityLevel,
        bmr,
        tdee,
        firstName,
        lastName,
      });

      console.log("User created and saved to Firestore:", docRef.id);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating account:", error);
      
    }
  }
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: i fixed my problem. i had to use initialise auth as `auth = getAuth(app)` and db as `db = getFirestore(app)`